# How do I create an expandable conditional with a loop inside?

Tags: conditionals, loops, latex3, expl3

I need to create an expandable conditional that uses a loop (that is, a `..._map_function:`). It should either return `true` from inside the loop, or return `false` otherwise. In a 'normal' programming language it would look something like this (where `p` is some predicate):

```
for each e in S {
    if p(e) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

A naive translation to LaTeX3 would look something like this (using l3prop as an example):

```
\cs_new:Nn \loop_body:nn {
    \bool_if:nn
        { p(#1, #2) }
        { \prg_return_true: }
}

\prop_map_function:NN \l_prop \loop_body:nn
\prg_return_false:
```

But that doesn't work, because `\prg_return_false:` will always appear in the input stream, even after a possible `\prg_return_true:`, and that is not allowed.

So how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the 'recommended' way, but it seems to work quite well:

```
\cs_new:Nn \loop_body:nn {
    \bool_if:nn
        { p(#1, #2) }
        { \prop_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
}

\prop_map_function:NN \l_prop \loop_body:nn
\prg_return_false:
```

`\prop_map_break:n` breaks the loop and puts some tokens in the input stream afterwards. `\use_i:nn` will then discard `\prg_return_false:`. This requires `\prg_return_false:` to appear immediately after the loop.

Comment: Given the functions currently available in `expl3`, yes, this is the solution I would suggest.